# Apply a script on a html file called by Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Everything is in the title ...

I created a code running on an element range:

```js
(function($){
    $('.range').each(function(){
        var range = $(this);
        range.on('input', function(){
            range.next().text($(this).val());
        })
        .next().text(range.val());
    });
})(jQuery);
```

I wish it also works on the same element called by Ajax.

```js
$('.ajax-global').on('click', function(){
    var param = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.ajax-window').load('./Ajax/' + param + '.php');
});
```

Here is a practical example of these tags Range: [online example](http://scriptura.github.io/#index-ranges).

If I call the same html code via Ajax, javascript does not apply to the latter. [Code with Ajax](http://scriptura.github.io/#index-ajax) (press the "Welcome Stackoverflow" button).

How to proceed? This is a dilemma that I can not solve, and that for a while ...

EDIT :

I remembered a useful function: $.getScript(), I'm almost there:

```
$('.ajax-global').on('click', function(){
    var param = $(this).attr('id');
    // Ouverture dans une fenêtre ajax généraliste :
    $('.ajax-window').load('./Ajax/' + param + '.php', function() {
        $.getScript( "./Scripts/Public/Scripts.js");
    });
});
```

It works ... except that the file called is reapplied to the entire document, whereas I want to limit only to new html elements called via Ajax (in order to limit the bugs).

Comment: Sorry it is not clear at all what you are asking. Please include any relevant code in the question itself.

Comment: jQuery `.delegate` method might help http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: Exact is a delegation I want to do, but I do not know how ...

Answer (score 0):

Your request to http://scriptura.github.io/Ajax/ajax-alsa.php returns html without any scripts. It is correctly inserted into DOM.

```
h2 class="h3">Welcome Stackoverflow !</h2>
<p class="message-info">The following code - called via Ajax - is not functional for the time necessary because the script is not associated. The imput type ranks should be able to display a number in the top right of the slide (<a href="./#index-ranges">see a working example on this page</a>).</p>
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <input type="range" name="a" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="50" class="range"/>
    <output>--</output>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Which script would you like to be executed?

Comment: I took the Range tag as an example to my question, but in reality I would potentially be able to apply all scripts javascript file called by the web page.

Comment: I may have found a track. See my original post updated ...